# How do I split a text columns rows base on a delimiter or phrase and keep the name on each split?

Tags: python, dataframe, split, reshape

I have a movies review dataframe with two columns: Name of Movie and Review. I want to split the review into sentences based on delimiter .,?! or a phrase. I then want to take that split review and move it one column down while also keeping the name of the movie one row down. The point is to make sentiment analysis easier based on each sentence or phrase.

```
df[review] = df['review'].str.split('. or ? or ! or ?').reshape(0,1)

movie1.........Great movie...................................................................................................
movie1.........and Alot of action............................................ movie2.........What did I think?..........................................................................................
movie2..........It was a horrible...........................................................................................
movie2..........and waste of money!!..............................
```

Comment: Please, can you be more specific giving an example of what is the input (data you have) and what is the output (data you want)?

Comment: @GabrielPellegrino its a data frame with columns of name of movie and a persons review of the movie.Think MovieLens data set. The review can be multiple lines of review for one movie. I want to split the review into multiple sentences with each sentence in its own row with the name of the movie as first column and review as the other column.

Answer (score 0):

df.Review.str.split('.').apply(Series, 1).stack()